# Why htaccess redirect code not work correctly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-services, apache2

I have this code to redirect if `REQUEST_URI` not start with one of the keywords you see, but its not work in my new server!

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/$"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/blog(.*)$"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/page(.*)$"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/faq(.*)$"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/users(.*)$"
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "http://example.com/blog/$1" [L,R=301]
```

This code worked perfectly on my previous server!

by testing in https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it should be work!

Comment: When you say it doesn’t work, what actually happens?

Comment: @NigelPeck all urls redirect to example.com/blog (urls that starts with page | faq | users)

Comment: I would again suggest the use of `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6` to find out what `mod_rewrite` rules are actually used resulting in your effects. RewriteRules can be active in different locations (server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess) and maybe you are not aware of all on the new server?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Please post your entire `.htaccess` file. If you change the `301` to `303`, do you see this in the network traffic? Do you have access to the server config?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled?
You need to have an

{RewriteEngine on}

in your httpd.conf or above the conditions/rules in your .htaccess

**Edit**: Because of the lack of good formatting in the comments I add the enabling of the mod_rewrite logging here, too:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
ErrorLog "path/to/log"
ServerName .....
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Assuming you have apache 2.4 or higher, you probably will give the logging a try with {LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6}

Comment: how to use LogLevel ? should I paste this code to end of .httaccess ?

Comment: The `LogLevel` directive is part of the apache server configuration and it's context is  **server config, virtual host, directory**. So using the .htaccess is not possible in that case. You can use it like
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
    ErrorLog "path/to/log"
    ServerName .....
    ...
</VirtualHost>`
Using it like that, it's only enabled for your specific VirtualHost and written into your `ErrorLog` - there you can see the 'way' the rewrite is done very, very precise. E.g. shortcuts or loop are obvious then.

Comment: Although if mod_rewrite wasn't enabled then presumably there wouldn't be any redirect at all? Unless _something else_ entirely is issuing the redirect?